# Variable autoescape in Smarty templates

Tags: smarty

I have recently found out that Smarty, differently from Django template engine, does not escape variables automatically and I need to put |escape next to most of the variables in my templates.

Following the docs, http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.default.modifiers.tpl I need to set default modifiers, needn't I?

So, here's my code:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->default_modifiers = array('escape:"htmlall"');
```

... and still variables ARE NOT escaped until I add |escape next to them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Smarty 3, try this:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->loadFilter(Smarty::FILTER_VARIABLE, "htmlentities");
```

Tadà!

**Update:** `Smarty::FILTER_VARIABLE` is undocumented as of 28/11/2014. Use [`$smarty->escape_html = true`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl) if you want to stick to [offical docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl).

Comment: or even simpler: [`$smarty->escape_html = true`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl)

Comment: Is there any documentation of how this works? I can't find any mention of the `Smarty::FILTER_VARIABLE` part...

Comment: @IMSoP I can't find it too. My answer is two year old, maybe they changed things or just docs. Consider rodneyrehm comment if you want to use something that is officially documented. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this feature was removed from Smarty v3, and docs are outdated. See:

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=62207

I'd recommend a workaround - which is template level. Either create a new style v3 function to take care of filtration, or, do a simple include.

#### Include method

Put this in a clean.tpl file:
`{$text|escape:htmlall}`

Then invoke as `{include file=clean.tpl text=$myvariabletofilter}`

#### Function method

The new functions in Smarty could also take care of that:

```
{function clean}
{$text|escape:htmlall}
{/function}
```

And invoke as `{clean text=$myvariabletofilter}`

As always, make sure that these things get trimmed right and don't insert unncessary spaces.

Comment: What would be the faster approach to escape variables in all the templates (I have plenty of them) without having to include the same thing in every template. I guess it could somehow be possible to do in PHP before outputting html.

Comment: Problem is that you can't seem to turn filtration on/off for particular items.  Though, I was hedging a bet on you having or wanting a streamlined way to output these in the first place. In other words, instead of two lines that look like <input type="text" name="myname1" value="{$myvar1}" /> you could have created a unique file / function to output these the same exact way - might help out in the long run to avoid this shotgun process. Like {textfield name=$myname value=$myvalue}