# How can I tell smarty to apply `htmlentities` to all output/display strings?

Tags: php, smarty

**Warning: I am totaly new to smarty !**

I have inherited a bunch of smarty templates that capture and display user input . So far ok.

However on displaying the data in the browser the smarty templates do not escape any html input made by a user instead it is rendered. If the user entered `<script>alert('alert')</script>` this
will produce an alert box !

I set `$escape_html`  in the Smarty.class.php had all templates compiled but no success.

I have been reading about modifiers `{string|htmlentities}` but still don't get it, where to apply this.

How can I tell smarty to apply `htmlentities` to all output/display strings ?
Do I have to crawl into all the template files to achive this ?

Smarty   'version' => '4.2.0'
I have deleted alle compiled templates befor trying anything new.
Have set the public smarty class variable $escape_html=true, but it has no effect. I still get my alert boxes.

Comment: Use the `escape` modifier to escape the content of the variable before printing it, see https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/designers/language-modifiers/language-modifier-escape.html

Comment: Thanks @Progman. I have seen this and it looks like I have to do this in every template, all in all I have 939 smarty->assign calls. This is not the route I want to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable autoescape in Smarty templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777474/variable-autoescape-in-smarty-templates)

Comment: @Progman $smarty->escape_html does not work

Comment: Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have. Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Have you recompiled your templates as mentioned on https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/programmers/api-variables/variable-escape-html.html?

Comment: @Progman, thanks for your help, but I think I will augment smarty->assig() to incorporate the feature I need. Thanks again

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't), `$smarty->escape_html` and/or `|escape` will do that for you. If it doesn't, add a MCVE to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STUPID ME !**

RTFM !

from the documentation

*Template designers can choose to selectively disable this feature by adding the nofilter flag: {$variable nofilter}.*

That is what the template designer did in several places...

```
{$datenreport[r].fruhere_Beschwerden|nl2br nofilter}
```

Because of nofilter set the section
in class Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Print_Expression

```
$output = "htmlspecialchars((string) {$output}, ENT_QUOTES, addslashes(Smarty::$_CHARSET) . "')";
```

Is skiped.

All is fine